What is this fruit from Cambodia? (orange skin, 3cm, orange juicy flesh, very stick white substance)
I saw this fruit in Thailand but was told it's from Cambodia:
Orange skin, ~3cm:

Orange juicy flesh:

The top has a very stick white substance  (the stickiness is quite similar to longkongs):

What is this fruit?

Have you tried it?

Not 100% sure, but this seems to be Willughbeia edulis, which is a climbing vine found from SE Asia through to India.
The fruit are yellow or orange, about the size of a lemon, have faint stripes on them and exude a latex from the stem end when cut. The latex forms a weak rubber after exposure to air. The latex also comes from cut stems and broken leaves.
I got this image from Plant Genetic Conservation Project Under the Royal Initiative of Her Royal Highness Princess Maha Chakri Sirindhorn, where you can see the similar shape and the stripes:

